# How to show the accumulative push notification instead of showing multiple notifications that tend to appear at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, delayed-job

Whenever a new event is added, a push notification is sent to the user. If ten events are added in row, ten push notifications will be sent to the user, a behavior that will be annoying.

I'd like to have it like this: if ten events are added in row, or added very near to each other regarding time, only one push notification will be sent to each user, saying: `"#{event.name} and 19 others events added that match your interests."`.

Here's what I've done so far:

Added a field `last_sent_notification` in `users` table. Each time a new event is added, it is checked that the created event isn't in the 2 minutes radius of `last_sent_notification`, and a notification is fired.

If a new created event is in the 2 minutes radius of `last_sent_notification`, a background job is created, that will wait for 2 minutes for any other upcoming event, and will fire after 2 minutes. If a new event is created while the 2-minute-wait, the notification will take into account all the events created during that 2-minute-wait.

The only disadvantage to this problem is: as an event is added, the notification won't be sent right away. There will be a delay of 2 minutes.

Is there any design pattern or optimum solution that could better do this job?

Comment: Simply follow the docs : http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

Comment: @NicolasSimon it's required at the server end.

Comment: so what did you settle on in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot simpler for you to use [Collapsible messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages), which is designed just for this sort of scenario.

> A collapsible message is a message that may be replaced by a new
>   message containing the same collapse key if it has yet to be delivered
>   to the device.

All you need to do is to set the `collapse_key` parameter.

If this is not what you really want, what you are looking for is a queue and send mechanism. This sort of thing can be done with redis quite easily. Your current server side app merely pushes GCM notifications on the redis queue. If there is already a message for the given user it is replaced.

Then you need to have another thread that constantly monitors the redis queue and sends messages that are older than n minutes.

Comment: Is it server-related or client-related stuff?

Comment: Arsan ali. It's simply a matter of adding 1 line of code to your GCM sender aka the server app

Comment: I went through that document. It isn't what I want. What's written there: it will send the user all the notifications, but only the latest one will be shown on user's mobile if all the earlier notifications share the same `collapse_key`.

Comment: What I want is a combined-effect-notification. The `collapse_key` scenario works perfect for the case of sports, in which a user needs to be updated with the latest score. The user doesn't care what was the score 30 sec ago; all he cares is: what's the latest score.